# Segmented Python turtle drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way we can draw something in boxes so that when boxes are arranged in order that it creates a whole picture. I have drawn an image and now I want into break into four boxes so that each box draws a part of the picture:

```
from turtle import *
y=0

def head():
    color('green')
    fd(160)
    x=xcor()
    seth(90)
    begin_fill()
    #color('green')
    circle(x/2,180)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    goto(33,37)
    pendown()
    dot(13,'black')
    penup()
    goto(126,37)
    pendown()
    dot(13,'black')
    penup()
    home()
    pendown()
    hideturtle()
    fd(160)
    seth(90)
    circle(x/2,60)
    right(90)
    pensize(5)
    fd(30) 

    penup()
    home()
    #pendown()
    hideturtle()
    fd(160)
    seth(90)
    circle(x/2,120)
    right(90)
    pensize(5)
    pendown()
    fd(30)
    penup()
    home()
    penup()

def body():
    pensize(0)

    home()
    showturtle()
    goto(0,-7)
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    fd(160)
    right(90)
    fd(120)
    right(90)
    fd(160)
    y=ycor()
    right(90)
    fd(120)
    end_fill()

def legs():
    penup()
    #color('red')
    goto(33,-169)
    pendown()
    pensize(32)
    fd(43)
    penup()
    goto(130,-169)
    pendown()
    fd(43)
    penup()

def hands():
    home()
    pensize(30)
    goto(-18,-77)
    pendown()
    left(90)
    fd(65)
    penup()
    goto(179,77)
    pendown()
    fd(65)
    penup()
    fd(100)
    hideturtle()
    circle(100)
    circle(100,360,59)


hideturtle()

head()
body()
legs()
hands()
done()
```

Comment: please share the code you wrote so far

Comment: @TomažBratanič I have edit the question with code I have written so far

Comment: That is not valid Python code.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: @MadPhysicist well the code works but I want to build this image by creating four blocks

Answer (score 0):

For maximum control over the quality of the image, the best approach is to break an image up externally into separate GIF images and load them into cursors using the `register_shape()` and `shape()` methods.

However, if you really want to draw them, here's a rough example.  I'm not using 'boxes' but just drawing elements of the shape that can then be dragged around to produce a final drawing:

```
from turtle import *

ANTENNA_WIDTH = 5
ANTENNA_HEIGHT = 30
HEAD_RADIUS = 80

def head():

    begin_poly()

    setheading(90)
    circle(HEAD_RADIUS, 60)
    current_heading = heading()
    setheading(60)
    forward(ANTENNA_HEIGHT)
    backward(ANTENNA_HEIGHT)
    setheading(current_heading)
    circle(HEAD_RADIUS, 60)
    current_heading = heading()
    setheading(120)
    forward(ANTENNA_HEIGHT)
    backward(ANTENNA_HEIGHT)
    setheading(current_heading)
    circle(HEAD_RADIUS, 60)

    end_poly()

    register_shape("head", get_poly())

    reset()

BODY_HEIGHT = 120

def body():

    begin_poly()

    right(90)
    forward(BODY_HEIGHT)
    right(90)
    forward(HEAD_RADIUS * 2)
    right(90)
    forward(BODY_HEIGHT)

    end_poly()

    register_shape("body", get_poly())

    reset()

LEG_LENGTH = 43
LEG_WIDTH = 32

def legs():

    begin_poly()

    forward(LEG_WIDTH)
    setheading(-90)
    forward(LEG_LENGTH)
    circle(LEG_WIDTH / 2, 180)
    forward(LEG_LENGTH)
    setheading(0)

    forward(LEG_WIDTH)
    setheading(-90)
    forward(LEG_LENGTH)
    circle(LEG_WIDTH / 2, 180)
    forward(LEG_LENGTH)
    setheading(0)

    forward(LEG_WIDTH)

    end_poly()

    register_shape("legs", get_poly())

    reset()

ARM_WIDTH = 30
ARM_LENGTH = 65

def arm():

    begin_poly()

    setheading(90)
    circle(ARM_WIDTH / 2, 180)
    forward(ARM_LENGTH)
    circle(ARM_WIDTH / 2, 180)

    end_poly()

    register_shape("arm", get_poly())

    reset()

head()
head_turtle = Turtle("head")
head_turtle.color("green")
head_turtle.setheading(90)
head_turtle.penup()
head_turtle.goto(150, 150)

body()
body_turtle = Turtle("body")
body_turtle.color("green")
body_turtle.setheading(90)
body_turtle.penup()
body_turtle.goto(-150, -150)

legs()
legs_turtle = Turtle("legs")
legs_turtle.color("green")
legs_turtle.setheading(90)
legs_turtle.penup()
legs_turtle.goto(150, -150)

arm()
left_arm_turtle = Turtle("arm")
left_arm_turtle.color("green")
left_arm_turtle.setheading(90)
left_arm_turtle.penup()
left_arm_turtle.goto(-150, 150)

right_arm_turtle = Turtle("arm")
right_arm_turtle.color("green")
right_arm_turtle.setheading(90)
right_arm_turtle.penup()
right_arm_turtle.goto(0, 0)

hideturtle()

def drag_handler(turtle, x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)  # disable ondrag event inside drag_handler
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y, turtle=turtle: drag_handler(turtle, x, y))

head_turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: drag_handler(head_turtle, x, y))
body_turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: drag_handler(body_turtle, x, y))
legs_turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: drag_handler(legs_turtle, x, y))
left_arm_turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: drag_handler(left_arm_turtle, x, y))
right_arm_turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: drag_handler(right_arm_turtle, x, y))

mainloop()
```

Although the turtle documentation shows just using `goto()` as a drag event handler, you won't be happy with the result.  The above handler is just a `goto()` wrapped in code that disables and reenables the event so they don't stack up while you're dragging the element.

**STARTING SCREEN**

[image]

**SCREEN AFTER DRAGGING**

[image]